# Linq Query with using sum and order by

Tags: c#, .net, linq, entity-framework, entity-framework-4

i have class like below,

```
public class SiteActionMap
{
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string ImageName { get; set; }
        public int ParentId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public  virtual ICollection<SiteActionMap> Childrens { get; set; }
        public  virtual SiteActionMap Parent { get; set; }
        public bool Active { get; set; }

}
```

and i want to get a list with order by Children counts.

i am trying something like this,but i didnt work.

```
List<SiteActionMap> list = dbContext.SiteActionMap
                .Include(m => m.Childrens)
                .Include(m => m.Parent)
                .OrderBy(i => i.Childrens.Count)
                ToList();
```

how i can sort my list with children counts?

Comment: OrderByDescending didnt work,

Comment: Are you sure about the position of the semicolon in your second example? This shouldn't compile...

Comment: yes but how can i?question is...

Comment: I can't help but grammar troll a little bit, but Children is already plural.  The two answers below are correct.  Even if ICollection has a Count property, it may not map to the DB context, but the Count() method will.

Comment: I can't check at the moment, but are you a victim of lazy loading here?  Maybe a .ToList() before the first .Include()?

Comment: @MikeCurtis i aware that lazy loading

Comment: @tobias - are you getting an error message ? or how do you know that it doesn't work ? And you are missing a dot before ToList() in your example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adding on to what lbruder said, isn't Count a method () in this case?

```
List<SiteActionMap> list = dbContext.SiteActionMap
                .Include(m => m.Childrens)
                .Include(m => m.Parent)
                .OrderByDescending(i => i.Childrens.Count())
                .ToList();
```

Comment: its work but  OrderBy(i => i.Childrens.Count()) didnt work?why?

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried this? Just remove the semicolon after the Order... line and continue the command:

```
List<SiteActionMap> list = dbContext.SiteActionMap
                .Include(m => m.Childrens)
                .Include(m => m.Parent)
                .OrderByDescending(i => i.Childrens.Count)
                .ToList();
```